# Android EventBus use singletone class to handle all events

Tags: java, android

in this below class i try to handle all events on application. i dont like to write some class to handle theme, in EventBus documentation, that use class constructor, my class must be singleton to be has public, then i wrote simple class as :

```
public class SignalEvents {
    private boolean internetConnectionState;
    private boolean activityMarketDetailState;

    public boolean isInternetConnectionState() {
        return internetConnectionState;
    }

    public void setInternetConnectionState(boolean internetConnectionState) {
        this.internetConnectionState = internetConnectionState;
    }

    public boolean isActivityMarketDetailState() {
        return activityMarketDetailState;
    }

    public void setActivityMarketDetailState(boolean activityMarketDetailState) {
        this.activityMarketDetailState = activityMarketDetailState;
    }
}
```

now, for eventBus and send event i try to use:

```
SignalEvents signal = new SignalEvents();
EventBus.getDefault().post(signal.setActivityMarketDetailState(true));
```

but then i get error :

```
Error:(98, 67) error: 'void' type not allowed here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post objects. For example:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new ActivityMarketDetailStateChanged(true));
```

And have such a class:

```
public class ActivityMarketDetailStateChanged {
    public final boolean newState;

    public ActivityMarketDetailStateChanged(boolean newState) {
        this.newState = newState;
    }
}
```

And then register to subscribe to those events, depending on if you are using EventBus 2.x or 3.x, assuming version 3:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(signal);
```

Need a subscribe method to receive it in  your SignalEvents class:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(ActivityMarketDetailStateChanged event) {
    setActivityMarketDetailState(event.newState);
}
```

Comment: can i use singleton class?

Comment: Sure thing, doesn't matter.

Comment: but i cant do that, could you fix my class?

Comment: Oh! i'm so sorry sir, me means was use one class to handle all events, not some class for each event :) in my class i try to handle InternetConnection and ActivityState on one class not two class

Comment: One class to handle the logic indeed, your SignalEvents. But to transfer the event you need an event class to post. Post takes an object, not some method reference.

Comment: could you help me on this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191276/android-get-eventbus-event-on-fragment-not-working

Comment: how to use in Singleton class?