# Android get EventBus event on fragment not working

Tags: android

after define event class and post event on Activity `onBackPressed()` i cant get event on fragment, some my activities opening above this fragment which that is child of MainActivity. i want to get some events that post from other opening activitis, but my code doesnt get this event on Fragment, but i can post event from Activity `onBackPressed()`

**SignalActivityMarketDetailStateEvents class:**

```
public class SignalActivityMarketDetailStateEvents {
    private boolean activityMarketDetailState;

    public SignalActivityMarketDetailStateEvents(boolean activityMarketDetailState) {
        this.activityMarketDetailState = activityMarketDetailState;
    }

    public boolean isActivityMarketDetailState() {
        return activityMarketDetailState;
    }
}
```

**ActivitySecond :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new SignalActivityMarketDetailStateEvents(true)); 
}
```

**Fragment to get event:**

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEventMainThread(SignalActivityMarketDetailStateEvents event) {
    Log.e("EventBus ","Received");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

in my Fragment this line doesnt work after post event:

```
Log.e("EventBus ","Received");
```

Comment: Does fragment attached to Activity?

Comment: @SergeyShustikov yes sir, fragment attached on MainActivity and, i want to get posted event on other activity

Comment: I will dissapoint you, but you can't. Sending & Receiving events should processed thought **one instance** of Activity

Comment: Ok. I got it.

You need pass back data from child Activity to parent Activity? yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mindful of the life cycle's of those activities. You could use the sticky events (`postSticky`) . Or update the state in some singleton and read that in `onResume`.

Comment: Thanks. Please let me to test it